# Understand kernel panic ( RHEL with kernel (2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64) )

Tags: linux, crash, kernel, rhel6, panic

I am a beginner w.r.t analyzing kernel panics i would like to know if i am missing anything in my analysis 
Following is part of the dump generated during Panic

```
<6>generic-usb 0003:14E1:3500.0062: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [PenMount PM1302] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.1/input0
<6>CPUFREQ: ondemand sampling_rate_max sysfs file is deprecated - used by: sosreport
<6>CPUFREQ: Per core ondemand sysfs interface is deprecated - sampling_rate_max
<6>CPUFREQ: Per core ondemand sysfs interface is deprecated - sampling_rate_min
<6>CPUFREQ: Per core ondemand sysfs interface is deprecated - sampling_rate
<6>CPUFREQ: Per core ondemand sysfs interface is deprecated - up_threshold
<6>CPUFREQ: Per core ondemand sysfs interface is deprecated - ignore_nice_load
<6>CPUFREQ: Per core ondemand sysfs interface is deprecated - powersave_bias
<6>warning: `turbostat' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
<4>FileAccess module was removed successfully. Version is - 10.6.0.201
<1>BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffa01f1b24
<1>IP: [<ffffffffa01f1b24>] 0xffffffffa01f1b24
<4>Kernel PGD 1a91067 PUD 1a95063 PMD 81caa6067 PTE 0
<4>User   PGD 82e362067 PUD 82e365067 PMD 0 
<4>Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP 
<4>last sysfs file: /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
<4>CPU 2 
<4>Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy nfs lockd fscache auth_rpcgss nfs_acl sunrpc i915 nvidia_modeset(P)(U) ip6table_mangle ip6table_filter ip6_tables coretemp cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq freq_table mperf ipv6 ipt_LOG xt_limit nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_state nf_conntrack iptable_filter iptable_mangle ip_tables microcode iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support sg joydev serio_raw i2c_i801 lpc_ich mfd_core shpchp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek e1000e ptp snd_hda_codec_generic pps_core snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc nvidia_drm(P)(U) nvidia(P)(U) ipmi_msghandler ext4 jbd2 mbcache sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crc_t10dif ahci xhci_hcd drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit i2c_core video output dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod [last unloaded: fileaccess_mod_100600201]
<4>
<4>Pid: 15740, comm: python Tainted: P           -- ------------    2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64 #1 Advantech AxisPC/MAHOBAY
<4>RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa01f1b24>]  [<ffffffffa01f1b24>] 0xffffffffa01f1b24
<4>RSP: 0018:ffff88051b4afef8  EFLAGS: 00010202
<4>RAX: 0000000000000005 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000002
<4>RDX: ffff880822f2d198 RSI: ffff880686ea0280 RDI: ffff880587a41000
<4>RBP: ffff88051b4aff48 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
<4>R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000241
<4>R13: 0000000000e2f940 R14: 00000000000001b6 R15: 0000000000000000
<4>FS:  00007f972d53d700(0000) GS:ffff88002c300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
<4>CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
<4>CR2: ffffffffa01f1b24 CR3: 000000056067e000 CR4: 00000000001607e0
<4>DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
<4>DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
<4>Process python (pid: 15740, threadinfo ffff88051b4ac000, task ffff880576372ab0)
<4>Stack:
<4> ffffffff815642c2 ffffffff815642ce ffffffff815642c2 ffffffff815642ce
<4><d> ffffffff815642c2 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
<4><d> 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffff815643a7
<4>Call Trace:
<4> [<ffffffff815642c2>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xa2/0x152
<4> [<ffffffff815642ce>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xae/0x152
<4> [<ffffffff815642c2>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xa2/0x152
<4> [<ffffffff815642ce>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xae/0x152
<4> [<ffffffff815642c2>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xa2/0x152
<4> [<ffffffff815643a7>] system_call_fastpath+0x35/0x3a
<4> [<ffffffff815642ce>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xae/0x152
<4>Code:  Bad RIP value.
<1>RIP  [<ffffffffa01f1b24>] 0xffffffffa01f1b24
<4> RSP <ffff88051b4afef8>
<4>CR2: ffffffffa01f1b24
```

as far as i understand the panic is caused because of

```
<4>FileAccess module was removed successfully. Version is - 10.6.0.201
<1>BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffa01f1b24
```

Comment: `RIP` is the **instruction pointer** on x86_64. So the error message `Bad RIP value` means that the code tries to execute an instruction on wrong (unmapped) address `0xffffffffa01f1b24`. If you want someone to **fix the error**, then Stack Overflow is a wrong place for such requests. Just report the error on appropriate bug tracker. If you want us to **help** you in fixing the error, then you is expected to provide much more information.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i am more intrested in understanding the contents of a crash 
Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Describing every part of the `BUG:` report would be **too lengthy** for Stack Overflow (and you certainly could find that description somewhere else). Do you want an explanation about the **particular** line(s) in the log? Note, that unless the core reason of the bug is known, interpretation of specific BUG report is mostly **opinion-based** (*guesses*), which also doesn't fit for Stack Overflow format.